# crown molding cope inside corner cope not fit (butted piece isn't flush)

Tags: trim-carpentry

The inside coped corner doesn't fit (4 5/8th FJ primed crown). It meets at the top too soon so then it leaves a wide gap if I fit the coped piece to the wall or if I fit the coped piece to the butted piece then it is angled down and off the wall by 6". I measured the profile against a framing square and the ceiling part extends 2 5/8ths in. When I slid a thin ruler between butted piece to profile end it measured 3 inches. Granted, that is 3/8ths inch but that seems to be a huge variance that perhaps no coped joint can fit? (does this sound right?)

I also thick textured ceiling and tried to sand it down where the butt piece should rest upon the ceiling and wall, especially near the joints. However, I believe I nailed the butted piece too far forward and when I checked the bottom profile to wall degree it was way off 90 (should always be mounted at 90 to wall regardless of wall angle, or so I think), which if this is the issue then I know it is my own fault because I stood on a ladder nearly two feet away and tried to use the nail gun to push the piece against the wall instead of moving furniture, holding the piece against the wall as flush as possible, and nailing.

I need some advice...can I use a trim prybar to ease out the already installed piece about 2 feet from corner and then re-shoot nails when lined up and properly and flush against the wall? If I do, and if this 'pulls back' the profile piece from 3" to 2 5/8ths" then the coped piece should fit, right???

I'm trying to avoid removing the entire piece. An alternative is to keep the piece attached but use a multi-tool and cut through the already-shot nails while holding the molding up (it is still nailed further upstream on the crown board) and then just align properly and reshoot. I'm not worried about prying against studs and joists but am concerned about the prybar on ceiling where I cross-nailed (I could probably leave them be and just 'force' them to align since it's drywall). Also, this is the first piece of crown I've ever installed and I think I may have learned an invaluable lesson about taking shortcuts and to never use the nail gun to push crown flush to wall without using my other hand.

Comment: A pic is worth a thousand words. And would help.

Comment: I'll try to get one tomorrow. In the meantime, I'm wondering if those who are experts or know crown copes if it is pretty much a failure if the butted crown piece bottom is not flush to the wall (I understand copes take care of wall and ceiling imperfections to a couple degrees) but if mounted incorrectly is this causing my misalignment?

Comment: I think I've resolved it. I ended up using an oscillating multi-tool with a metal cutting blade and just went behind the crown on both ceiling and wall and cut through the finish nails. I cut a few feet and notice it is just the crown piece is warped and I assumingly just pushed it up into the corner and nailed without aligning the crown to wall at 90 so that the profiles will match in a coped joint.